# MPI pbs output file is avaiable during the running time?

Tags: output, mpi, hpc, pbs

I am running a program, and I am using debug mode. In debug mode program print out some useful information, and i want to check it during the run. However i can't find the output file in the output directory.. is it available during the code or I can get it at the end of code.

there is job information :

```
Job Id: 420302.kavun-ib
Job_Name = pKmeans
Job_Owner = e1893122@nar-ib
resources_used.cput = 00:00:00
resources_used.mem = 8148kb
resources_used.vmem = 138560kb
resources_used.walltime = 20:27:15
job_state = R
queue = cenga
server = kavun-ib
Checkpoint = u
ctime = Wed Sep  3 14:40:27 2014
Error_Path = nar:/home1/e1893122/10m_data/pKmeans.err
exec_host = ceng33-ib/7+ceng33-ib/6+ceng33-ib/5+ceng33-ib/4+ceng33-ib/3+ce
ng33-ib/2+ceng33-ib/1+ceng33-ib/0+ceng34-ib/7+ceng34-ib/6+ceng34-ib/5+
ceng34-ib/4+ceng34-ib/3+ceng34-ib/2+ceng34-ib/1+ceng34-ib/0+ceng35-ib/
7+ceng35-ib/6+ceng35-ib/5+ceng35-ib/4+ceng35-ib/3+ceng35-ib/2+ceng35-i
b/1+ceng35-ib/0+ceng36-ib/7+ceng36-ib/6+ceng36-ib/5+ceng36-ib/4+ceng36
-ib/3+ceng36-ib/2+ceng36-ib/1+ceng36-ib/0+ceng37-ib/7+ceng37-ib/6+ceng
37-ib/5+ceng37-ib/4+ceng37-ib/3+ceng37-ib/2+ceng37-ib/1+ceng37-ib/0+ce
ng38-ib/7+ceng38-ib/6+ceng38-ib/5+ceng38-ib/4+ceng38-ib/3+ceng38-ib/2+
ceng38-ib/1+ceng38-ib/0+ceng39-ib/7+ceng39-ib/6+ceng39-ib/5+ceng39-ib/
4+ceng39-ib/3+ceng39-ib/2+ceng39-ib/1+ceng39-ib/0+ceng40-ib/7+ceng40-i
b/6+ceng40-ib/5+ceng40-ib/4+ceng40-ib/3+ceng40-ib/2+ceng40-ib/1+ceng40
-ib/0
Hold_Types = n
Join_Path = n
Keep_Files = n
Mail_Points = e
Mail_Users = "xxx@xxxx"
mtime = Wed Sep  3 14:42:13 2014
Output_Path = nar:/home1/e1893122/10m_data/pKmeans.out
Priority = 0
qtime = Wed Sep  3 14:40:27 2014
Rerunable = True
Resource_List.cput = 14400:00:00
Resource_List.mem = 20gb
Resource_List.nodect = 8
Resource_List.nodes = 8:ppn=8
Resource_List.walltime = 9600:00:00
session_id = 4383
Variable_List = PBS_O_HOME=/home1/e1893122,PBS_O_LANG=en_US.UTF-8,
PBS_O_LOGNAME=e1893122,
PBS_O_PATH=/usr/mpi/gcc/openmpi-1.2.8/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/loca
l/bin:/bin:/usr/bin,PBS_O_MAIL=/var/spool/mail/e1893122,
PBS_O_SHELL=/bin/bash,PBS_SERVER=nar,PBS_O_HOST=nar,
PBS_O_WORKDIR=/home1/e1893122/workspace/parallel-kmeans,
PBS_O_QUEUE=cenga
etime = Wed Sep  3 14:40:27 2014
submit_args = pKmeans.pbs
start_time = Wed Sep  3 14:40:57 2014
start_count = 1
```

Comment: I think those files are often available during the execution in your home directory, but I could be wrong about that. It could also be system specific.

Comment: The location of the spool directory for PBS/Torque is configurable. AFAIR, the default is a node-local directory somewhere in /var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the files depends on how Torque/PBS is configured. Sometimes they are created in the jobs working directory and other times they are created on the compute node and copied to the working directory once the job completes. If this is the case you should be able to find that output in PBS/Torque spool directory. /var/spool/torque/spool and /var/lib/torque/spool are two places to start looking. You can also work around this by redirecting your output to a file you specify

```
mpirun -np 8 ./a.out > /home/neouyghur/job_output
```

or

```
mpirun -np 8 ./a.out &> /home/neouyghur/job_output
```

to get both the stdout and stderr.

You may also want to look at the o, e, j, and k switches in the qsub man page as they can also effect how your output gets handled.

Comment: firstly thank you for your reply, but you may misunderstood my mean. I have redirected the output file, but normally I can't access them after end of the program not during the running.

Comment: I have posted my job information, could you check it and tell me the direction if possible... thank you..

Comment: I think I understand. After your job completes you are able to see pKmeans.out and pKmeans.err but you would like to see what your job is doing during the run. While your job is running, it is storing the jobs stdout and stderr on the first node of your job, the mother superior. In the output above it appears to be a machine called ceng33-ib. If you can ssh to ceng33-ib and look around in /var/spool/torque/spool you should see the files that are later copied to your home directory. Otherwise, you can redirect the output like shown in my answer and bypass torque entirely for future runs.

Comment: Ok, thank you... now My program is running, next time I will do as what you said.

Comment: do know why resources_used.cput = 00:00:00, it never changed?

Comment: Good to hear. Haven't had a chance to look at your cpu time question.

Comment: I looked at a few clusters and did a few quick searches and it seems that Torque can only report on processes that it starts. Ideally, all of your MPI processes would be started by Torque using the TM(Task Manager) API and Torque would be able to monitor them but this isn't always the case. If your MPI job has to start it's own processes by using SSH these can't be monitored by Torque and will not appear in the cput stats.

Answer (score 2):

If your output files are always in network-mounted locations then you can ask the admin to set

```
$spool_as_final_name true
```

in the mom's config file. This would have the output written directly to its final location instead of getting spooled elsewhere and then copied over.